# Why do I have error while building project?

Tags: android, kotlin

I watched the youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBCAWfztTrQ&t=8s&ab_channel=Stevdza-San) and implemented database in my project
Database.kt:

```
@Database(entities = [Result::class], version = DATABASE_VERSION, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ResultDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun resultDao(): ResultDao

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: ResultDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): ResultDatabase {
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE

        if (tempInstance != null) {
            return tempInstance
        }

        synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ResultDatabase::class.java,
                TABLE_NAME
            ).build()

            INSTANCE = instance

            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

}

ResultClass.kt:

```
@Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
data class Result(private val id: Int,
              private val cheatingEnabled: Boolean,
              private val cheatingSuccessful: Boolean,
              private val min: Long,
              private val max: Long,
              private val result: Long,
              private val time: LocalDateTime
```

)

ResultDao.kt:

```
@Dao
interface ResultDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun addResult(result: Result)

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM random_data ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getAllResults(): LiveData<List<Result>>
}
```

Repo.kt

```
class ResultsRepository(private val resultDao: ResultDao) {
    val resultHistory: LiveData<List<Result>> = resultDao.getAllResults()

    fun addResult(result: Result) {
        resultDao.addResult(result)
    }
}
```

Function that inserts data to database:

```
private fun insertDataToDatabase(min: Long,
                                 max: Long,
                                 result: Long,
                                 cheatingEnabled: Boolean,
                                 cheatingSuccessful: Boolean
) {
    val time = LocalDateTime.now()
    val resultEntity = Result(0, cheatingEnabled, cheatingSuccessful, min, max, result, time)
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.addResult(resultEntity)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:14: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
private final java.time.LocalDateTime time = null;
                                      ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:8: error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final int id = 0;
                  ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:9: error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final boolean cheatingEnabled = false;
                      ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:10: error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final boolean cheatingSuccessful = false;
                      ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:11: error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final long min = 0L;
                   ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:12: error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final long max = 0L;
                   ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:13: error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final long result = 0L;
                   ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:14: error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final java.time.LocalDateTime time = null;
                                      ^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:7: error: An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey
```

public final class Result {
^C:\Users\Maxim\AndroidStudioProjects\AdvancedNumberGenerator\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\advancednumbergenerator\database\Result.java:14: error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
private final java.time.LocalDateTime time = null;
^

How can I fix this error? Can it be connected with using LocalDateTime datatype and Long instead of int? But I don't even start inserting, I get errors while building. I saw similar questions and there people adviced to use json objects, but man from youtube has project without json and withoutany errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it be connected with using LocalDateTime datatype and Long instead of int?

Yes.

> But I don't even start inserting, I get errors while building

Room uses an annotation processor — that is the `kapt` statement you added to your `dependencies`. That annotation processor does not know what to do with a `LocalDateTime`. And, it cannot work with `private` Kotlin properties.

> How can I fix this error?

Start by removing the `private` keyword from those properties on `Result`. That should reduce the errors to 2, both for `LocalDateTime`.

Then, you will need to teach Room how to work with `LocalDateTime`.

For that, you will need a class with a pair of `@TypeConverter` functions that can convert between `LocalDateTime` and... something. In [this sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v2.0/T22-Room/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/repo/TypeTransmogrifier.kt), I have type converters between `Instant` and `Long`:

```kotlin
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import java.time.Instant

class TypeTransmogrifier {
  @TypeConverter
  fun fromInstant(date: Instant?): Long? = date?.toEpochMilli()

  @TypeConverter
  fun toInstant(millisSinceEpoch: Long?): Instant? = millisSinceEpoch?.let {
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(it)
  }
}
```

Then, you will need to add a `@TypeConverters` annotation (note the trailing `s`) to something to register your class with the `@TypeConverter` annotations. One simple place to do this is on your `@RoomDatabase` class, as I do in [this sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v2.0/T22-Room/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/repo/ToDoDatabase.kt):

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.TypeConverters

private const val DB_NAME = "stuff.db"

@Database(entities = [ToDoEntity::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(TypeTransmogrifier::class)
abstract class ToDoDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
  abstract fun todoStore(): ToDoEntity.Store

  companion object {
    fun newInstance(context: Context) =
      Room.databaseBuilder(context, ToDoDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME).build()
  }
}
```

Given those two things, in [my sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/tree/v2.0/T22-Room/ToDo), any of my entities can use `Instant`. You would do the same thing, just for `LocalDateTime` (or, perhaps, switch your entities from using `LocalDateTime` to using `Instant`).

You can read more about this in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters).